# Google Compute Engine Client FTP Access

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a client who's site is hosted on Google Compute Engine. They insist on having FTP access to the site. I am somewhat new to Google Compute Engine. I currently use FTP using Google's instructions. However my client will not know how to install the Google Cloud Console, download and convert the security keys, log in and move any files they upload in their folder using shell.

What I would like to do is install some kind of FTP server (proftpd or similar) install some kind of GUI they can log into to create users in the future and upload files using filezilla. However when I install proftpd on Compute Engine (Debian Wheezy) and I create a user to test before I install a GUI, the server keeps denying access.

Anyone with experience setting up FTP on Compute Engine for a client that can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set this up, but as far as I remember you need to specifically set up firewall rules to open the FTP port on your instances.